# ggplot2 calculate x_intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot two data series as follows, one Dm1 in red and another Dm2 in green.

[image: help x_intercept]

```
  p<-ggplot() +
  geom_line(data= Dm1, aes(x = x, y = y , color = "Dm1")) +
  geom_line(data= Dm2, aes(x = x, y = y, color = "Dm2")) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("Dm1", "Dm2"),
                      values = c("red", "green")) 


p+labs(x = "x in log scale", y="y in log scale", title = "help")+ 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.006262418)
```

I draw a line at position (y) = (0.006262418) on the green line, now I would like to calculate at what position of x it crosses the red line (x_intercept). How should I do this?

Comment: `geom_line` connects its points with straight lines, so interpolate between the `y` values in `Dm2` that are either side of 0.006262418

Comment: Thanks Calum, that was a very good suggestion. If any one else is looking into this problem, the answer to the duplicate question didn't help. I solved this by using `numpy.interp` from python and interploate.